# django static files are showing error while loading from aws-s3 bucket

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

PLease check the screenshots.

i am creating my aws-s3 bucket in above way.it is compying everything when i am using **python manage.py collectstatic**

But static files are showing error when i am checking from my view source .

please check last screenshot for **errors**

Comment: is the static files loading in the website? if yes. then the behaviour is ok, as you cannot see the contents directly when opening the url. or else make them public and then you can see

Comment: Yes. They are public.

Comment: but still not working

Comment: i mean the bucket

Comment: yes. bucket is public and i added awss3 full access

Comment: is there any issue with regions